# Cannot remove a set of chars in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a set of characters I want to remove from a string : `"/\[]:|<>+=;,?*'@`

I'm trying with :

```
private const string CHARS_TO_REPLACE = @"""/\[]:|<>+=;,?*'@";

private string Clean(string stringToClean)
{
    return Regex.Replace(stringToClean, "[" + Regex.Escape(CHARS_TO_REPLACE) + "]", "");
}
```

However, the result is strictly identical to the input with something like `"Foo, bar and other"`.

What is wrong in my code ?

This looks like a lot to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356425/c-sharp-3-0-remove-chars-from-string), but with a black list instead of a white list of chars, so I removed the not in `^` char.

Comment: Can you print out the regex that's being built?

Comment: It's `["/\\\[]:\|<>\+=;,\?\*'@]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a misunderstanding of how [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) works. From MSDN:

> Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes.

It works as expected, but you need to think of `Regex.Escape` as escaping metacharacters *outside* of a character class. When you use a character class, the things you want to escape *inside* are different. For example, inside a character class `-` should be escaped to be literal, otherwise it could act as a range of characters (e.g., `[A-Z]`).

In your case, as others have mentioned, the `]` was not escaped. For any character that holds a special meaning within the character class, you will need to handle them separately after calling `Regex.Escape`. This should do what you need:

```
string CHARS_TO_REPLACE = @"""/\[]:|<>+=;,?*'@";
string pattern = "[" + Regex.Escape(CHARS_TO_REPLACE).Replace("]", @"\]") + "]";

string input = "hi\" there\\ [i love regex];@";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Otherwise, you were ending up with `["/\\\[]:\|<>\+=;,\?\*'@]`, which doesn't have `]` escaped, so it was really `["/\\\[]` as a character class, then `:\|<>\+=;,\?\*'@]` as the rest of the pattern, which wouldn't match unless your string matched exactly those remaining characters.

Comment: They really should have make Regex.Escape escape `]` and `-`. There is no harm in escaping these out of character classes, and these *are* meta-characters (depending on context).

Answer (score 5):

You didn't escape the closing square bracket in `CHARS_TO_REPLACE`

Comment: `Regex.Escape` isn't catching the closing square, apparently. Neat.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned (but the answer has suddenly disappeared), `Regex.Escape` does not escape `]`, so you need to tweak your code:

```
    return Regex.Replace(stringToClean, "[" + Regex.Escape(CHARS_TO_REPLACE)
          .Replace("]", @"\]") + "]", " ");
```

Comment: Yeah, I conclude to the same solution... seems to be a small bug in the .Net framework.

Comment: yep, agreed! should be considered as a bug

Comment: @SteveB: Not a bug - `Regex.Escape` is not designed for building character sets! It's for adding a string literal as part of the search pattern.

Comment: Actually, this is not a bug. If you read the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx), you will find "If a closing bracket or brace is not preceded by its corresponding opening character, the regular expression engine interprets it literally.". Because I'm adding a leading bracket after the call to escape, I'm not satisfying this rule.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of characters within `CHARS_TO_REPLACE` which are special to Regex's and need to be escaped with a slash `\`.

This should work:

```
"/\[]:\|<>\+=;,\?\*'@
```

Comment: Didn't you see the call to `Regex.Escape` ?

Comment: Apparently not.  I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
 private static string Clean(string stringToClean)
    {

        string[] disallowedChars = new string[] {//YOUR CHARS HERE};

        for (int i = 0; i < disallowedChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringToClean= stringToClean.Replace(disallowedChars[i],""); 
        }

        return stringToClean;
    }
```

Comment: Why bother with the `.Contains` check?

Comment: That gives me a compile error - _"The best overloaded method match for `string.Replace(char, char)` has some invalid arguments"_

Comment: Whoops, thought you were iterating over a string literal

Answer (score 1):

Single-statement linq solution:

```
private const string CHARS_TO_REPLACE = @"""/\[]:|<>+=;,?*'@";

private string Clean(string stringToClean) {
    return CHARS_TO_REPLACE
        .Aggregate(stringToClean, (str, l) => str.Replace(""+l, ""));
}
```

Comment: Nice solution too. Another solution, more suited for very large stream, would be to use a combination of a StringReader and a StringBuilder. But as my string are quite small (<50 chars) and called very rarely (twice a month maybe), it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of knowledge, here is a variant suited for very large strings (or even streams). No regex here, simply a loop over each chars with a stringbuilder for storing the result :

```
class Program
{
    private const string CHARS_TO_REPLACE = @"""/\[]:|<>+=;,?*'@";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        var veryLargeString = wc.DownloadString("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

        using (var sr = new StringReader(veryLargeString))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            int readVal;
            while ((readVal = sr.Read()) != -1)
            {
                var c = (char)readVal;
                if (!CHARS_TO_REPLACE.Contains(c))
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```